# Bucle infinito después de leer una cadena

Tags: c++

Según lo que puse, si el nombre es = a FIN el bucle termina, pero en vez de hacer eso, justo cuando pongo el primer nombre (Sea cual fuere) El programa empieza a entrar en un bucle infinito:

```
int main()
{
    int edad, edadmayor, edadmenor, i;
    char nombre, nombremayor, nombremenor;
    edadmayor=0;
    edadmenor=0;
    nombre=' ';
    do
    {
        cout << "Ingrese el nombre de la persona y la fecha de nacimiento en formato AAAAMMDD" << endl;
        cin >> nombre;
        cin >> edad;
        if (edadmayor<edad)
        {
            edadmayor=edad;
            nombremayor=nombre;
        }
        else if (edadmenor>edad)
        {
            edadmenor=edad;
            nombremenor=nombre;
        }
        cout << "Si no quiere ingresar otro nombre, coloque 'FIN', si quiere seguir ingresando, toque cualquier tecla" << endl;
        cin >> nombre;
    } while (nombre!='FIN');
    cout << "La persona mas grande se llama " << nombremenor << " y nacio el " << edadmenor << endl;
    cout << "La persona mas joven se llama " << nombremayor << " y nacio el " << edadmayor << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creo que es cosa de la comparación, pero no recuerdo bien ahora C++... Estás comparando con igualdad una cadena de caracteres, no un string... Puede ser por eso?

Comment: `nombre`  está declarado como `char`. Tiene pinta de que eso no está bien. En un `char` sólo cabe una letra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es lo mismo un carácter (`char`) que una cadena de caracteres. Un carácter puede contener una única letra; por lo que jamás podrá contener las tres letras que componen la cadena `FIN`.

Por otro lado, en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) las cadenas de caracteres se delimitan con comillas dobles (`"`) si delimitas una palabra de cuatro o menos letras con comillas simples (`'`) lo que obtienes es un literal de número entero, en tu caso `4606286` que en hexadecimal es `0x46494E` que se corresponde con los [valores hexadecimales de las letras `F`, `I` y `N`](http://www.asciitable.com/) (`0x46` es ***F***, `0x49` es ***I*** y `0x4E` es ***N***).

Así que lo has hecho todo mal:

- Tienes que usar cadenas, no caracteres para guardar los nombres.
- Tienes que usar comillas dobles, no comillas simples para escribir cadenas.

Comment: Tiamo gracias <3